# how to call oracle function in mybatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I want to call Oracle function using Mybatis i tried Different way but did not get result.
please solve my issue.

```
 <select id="getNo" resultType="String" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
begin
     #{retval, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}  = CALL pc_sys.f_get_no
     (
      #{notyp, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
     #{ymdDate, mode=IN, jdbcType=DATE}
     );
end;
 </select>
```

**Error Contents :**

```
begin ? = CALL pc_sys.f_get_no ( ?, ? ); end;
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ; indicator
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ; indicator.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java

```
void getNo(Map<String,Object> mymap);
```

In Mapper.xml File

```
    <select id="getNo" resultType="String" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
     #{retval, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}  = CALL pc_sys.f_get_no
     (
      #{notyp, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
     #{ymdDate, mode=IN, jdbcType=DATE}
     );
end;
 </select>
```

Using this code I solved my issue.