# Return value from Oracle function using Mybatis

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I have looked at a number of StackOverflow questions on this issue but can't find one that makes any sense.   [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174108/how-to-call-oracle-function-in-mybatis) comes closest but doesn't show how to get the return value from the function.

Here's my mapper call:

```
public Long callMyFunction(@Param("recordId") Long recordId, @Param("otherId") Long otherId, @Param("date") Date date, @Param("comments") String comments);
```

Here's the mapper XML:

```
<select id="callMyFunction" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE"  resultType="java.lang.Long">
    {  #{resultId,javaType=java.lang.Long,jdbcType=NUMERIC,mode=OUT} = call MYSCHEMA.MYPACKAGE.my_function(
    #{recordId,jdbcType=NUMERIC,mode=IN},
    #{otherId,jdbcType=NUMERIC,mode=IN},
    #{date,jdbcType=DATE,mode=IN},
    #{comments,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN})}
</select>
```

The call works, but the return value (resultId) is always null.

Can anybody spot the problem?

Comment: Have you tried it with recordId, javaType=long (native type) rather than Long (object wrapper)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return directly the result, then the SQL call must be:
`SELECT MYSCHEMA.MYPACKAGE.my_function(...) FROM DUAL`

If you want to keep with calling the function in the procedure call style, that means the result is an OUT **parameter** (you env declared it OUT).
The minimum change would consist in adding a parameter to the mapper method signature:
`public Long callMyFunction(@Param("recordId") Long recordId, @Param("otherId") Long otherId, @Param("date") Date date, @Param("comments") String comments, @Param("resultIdContainer") Map<String, Long> resultIdContainer);`

In the XML: forget the *resultType*, this is for *select*s. And the call:
`{  #{resultIdContainer.resultId, javaType=java.lang.Long,jdbcType=NUMERIC,mode=OUT} = call ...`

Not that I use here a map to contain the resutlId: an indirection is required: the function will write the parameter 'result' value somewhere you can read later (after your mapper call), you can also use a class with a resultId property.

Comment: That was precisely what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: in the first variant `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: Fixed. It worked as it was in other DBMS, while in Oracle we must indeed select anything `FROM DUAL`

Comment: What if my jdbcType is Cursor?

Comment: Should be `call #{params.resultList, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, resultMap=myResultMap, mode=OUT} = my_function()` which is same principle as with procedure: `call  my_procedure(#{params.resultList, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, resultMap=myResultMap, mode=OUT})`. Note that `params` is used for input AND output. The mapper result type is `void`.